# Any advantage of XOR AL,AL + MOVZX EAX, AL over XOR EAX,EAX?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

I have some unknown C++ code that was compiled in Release build, so it's optimized. The point I'm struggling with is:

```
xor     al, al
add     esp, 8
cmp     byte ptr [ebp+userinput], 31h
movzx   eax, al
```

This is my understanding:

```
xor     al, al    ; set eax to 0x??????00 (clear last byte)
add     esp, 8    ; for some unclear reason, set the stack pointer higher
cmp     byte ptr [ebp+userinput], 31h ; set zero flag if user input was "1"
movzx   eax, al   ; set eax to AL and extend with zeros, so eax = 0x000000??
```

I don't care about line 2 and 3. They might be there in this order for pipelining reasons and IMHO have nothing to do with EAX.

However, I don't understand why I would clear AL first, just to clear the rest of EAX later. The result will IMHO always be `EAX = 0`, so this could also be

```
xor eax, eax
```

instead. What is the advantage or "optimization" of that piece of code?

Some background info:

I will get the source code later. It's a short C++ console demo program, maybe 20 lines of code only, so nothing that I would call "complex" code. IDA shows a single loop in that program, but not around this piece. The Stud_PE signature scan didn't find anything, but likely it's Visual Studio 2013 or 2015 compiler.

Comment: Is it possibly part of a loop that repeats from the `cmp` and so `al` is no longer zero in subsequent iterations?

Comment: @Jester: no, IDA does not show a loop.

Comment: IDA may be wrong with disassembly (very very unlikely, but possible). It may be also just missed optimization from compiler, probably confused by too complex C++ source or some unhelpful data type, which doesn't get compiled well. `xor eax,eax` would be superior in this case, avoiding `movzx` completely. Also it may be some kind of hand tuned "nop" padding, but I doubt that, using ordinary multibyte `nop` variant is better.

Comment: @Ped7g: I will get the source code later. It's a short demo program (C++ console, maybe 20 lines of code only). Stud_PE signature scan didn't find anything, but likely it's Visual Studio 2013 or 2015 compiler.

Comment: BTW, if it's not in loop, and it is not some kind of high frequency trading bot, or something else with real-time requirements and hard limits, then it doesn't matter, the total executable time went up by 2-3 cycles at most... but it saved probably few thousands of CPU cycles at optimizing stage of compiler ;)

Comment: @Ped7g Thanks for the insight. Hopefully the compiler cannot take that information into consideration. Maybe in 15 years the compiler asks my Facebook profile first and then determines whether or not I will execute that program at all :-)

Comment: That's negative, it will be too hard to predict whether you will be able to sell it somewhere in the future, for example by doing some proper pitch toward some dumb high frequency trading bot... That would cost probably few billions of cycles to decide, too costly. But for example [Profile-guided_optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profile-guided_optimization) is a real thing, i.e. after collecting somewhat meaningful runtime data, the compiler may focus optimizer on hot-spots of the code, and skip those single-time-executed to spend cycles in more meaningful way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xor al,al` is already slower than `xor eax,eax` on most CPUs.  e.g. [on Haswell/Skylake it needs an ALU uop and doesn't break the dependency on the old value of `eax`/`rax`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660139/how-exactly-do-partial-registers-on-haswell-skylake-perform-writing-al-seems-to).  It's equally bad on AMD CPUs, or Atom/Silvermont.  (Well, maybe not equally because AMD doesn't eliminate `xor eax,eax` at issue/rename, but it still has a false dependency which could serialize the new dependency chain with whatever used `eax` last).

On CPUs that do rename `al` separately from the rest of the register (Intel pre-IvyBridge), the `xor al,al` may still be recognized [as a zeroing idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and), but unless you actively want to preserve the upper bytes of the register, the best way to zero `al` is `xor eax,eax`.

Doing `movzx` on top of that just makes it even worse.

---

I'm guessing your compiler somehow got confused and decided it needed a 1-byte zero, but then realized it needed to promote it to 32 bits.  `xor` sets flags, so it couldn't `xor`-zero *after* the `cmp`, and it failed to notice that it could have just xor-zeroed `eax` before the `cmp`.

Either that or it's [something like Jester's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47189701/any-advantage-of-xor-al-al-movzx-eax-al-over-xor-eax-eax/47189913#comment81328744_47189701), where the `movzx` is a branch target.  Even if that's the case, `xor eax,eax` would still have been better because zero-extending into eax follows unconditionally on this code path.

I'm curious what compiler produced this from what source.

Comment: Would that incicate there's a line of C++ code like `byte x=something;` instead of e.g. `int x=something;`? (potentially, of course, not sure)

Comment: @ThomasWeller: I wouldn't even try to guess from the tiny fragment you showed.  That's plausible.  I was thinking that maybe a boolean condition was getting promoted to `int`, and the compiler only proved that it was always false too late to go and fix the rest of the code?  IDK, MSVC doesn't make the most efficient code.  I only rarely look at its output, so IDK what kind of source could trick it into being dumb like this.

Comment: Hehe, ok. At least my understanding of the ASM code seems to be fine and no obvious human brain issue late at night :-). Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: related: [tweaking C source to hand-hold compilers into making better asm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354978/why-is-this-c-code-faster-than-my-hand-written-assembly-for-testing-the-collat).  Sometimes when compilers are missing an optimization you can see in the asm, you can change the source.  IDK about a case like this where it's not even algorithmic, just plain stupid, though.

Comment: Thanks - maybe that's too much for me at the moment. I'll post the C++ MCVE when I get it.